# Cannot access before initialization - defining ENV vars across multiple files

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5

I have code that reference a local library, which has an environments file.

The folder structure looks like

```
> common-lib
-src
--Env
----index.js
--Services.js
----index.js
--index.js

> myapp
-src
--index.js
```

`/Env/index.js`:

```
export const SECRET_CREDENTIALS = {
    mykey: `IT'S THE KEY`
}
```

`/Services/index.js`:

```
import { SECRET_CREDENTIALS } from ".."

const KEY = SECRET_CREDENTIALS.mykey

export function showVar(orderCart) {
    return KEY
}
```

`index.js`:

```
export * from './Services'
export * from './Env'
```

Now, when I call `showVar` from the library in `myapp`, at `index.js`, I get an error saying cannot access `SECRET_CREDENTIALS` before it's initialized. The error is avoided if I move the `const KEY = SECRET_CREDENTIALS.messaging` into the function `showVar` itself.

Why is this happening, and how should I structure things properly so that the initialization order is correct?

Comment: Please show us clearly the contents of the individual files that you have *now* (with the problem), not what you *used* to have. Where is `functions.js` imported? Is `credentials.js` imported anywhere but in `env.js`? What does `functions.js` look like now you've made the change? (Please just remove the old structure, it's only confusing.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder edited

Comment: Is it `lib/function.js` or `lib/functions.js`? You've used one in a couple of places but you have `export * from './lib/function'`. (It's always best to use copy and paste to avoid introducing things like that into the question.) Just asking of the off-chance that you also have a `lib/function.js` file that has something throwing things off.

Comment: Similarly I assume `export someFunction() { }` is actualy `export function someFunction() { }` or similar?

Comment: Also, `import * from './api'` is a syntax error. It needs as `as `clause after the `*`. Or is that meant to be `export`? And then there's missing closing quotes elsewhere. So it's really hard to help you. It's really unclear what you're really doing, since what's shown is multiply-incorrect.

Comment: However, I've tried. :-) I've copied all of this to files, added the relevant `.js` to the names, assumed the `import * from './api'` should have an `as API` (given the use of `API` later), and run it in Node.js. Works just fine, no error.

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to vastly simplify my code to present it as a question here. Now I've gone and put this into a repo: https://github.com/imdavidmin/Temp

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Do `yarn start` in myapp folder and you should see the error in browser. You may have to do a `yarn link` to update where you download the repo to on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Because the export in the `common-lib` `index.js` exports the `showVar` first, before it exports `SECRET_CREDENTIALS`, and `showVar` is importing `SECRET_CREDENTIALS` from the library's `index.js`, it would be importing before  the var is available.

Either, import directly from `../Env`, or move the order of the exports in `common-lib`'s 'index.js'